# iOS Wallet Pass Auto Adjust Font Size

Tags: ios, passbook

I have a small problem regarding iOS Wallet Pass. I am trying to create a pass similar to the one created in "AZ Help" app, link to that app is given below. Its a `Coupon` type card, no biggie, everything is good. But, there is one problem I am unable to figure out. Actually I have even found a work around for it, but I just want to understand what is causing this issue.

The issue is when Change my phone's font size to bold. My text gets big and thus is truncated. While theirs(AZ Help's) does not, it seems that they have implemented `adjustFontSizeToWidth` or something. I am unable to find any such key or anything related to it.

So, the question becomes, How can I achieve that auto font size adjusting functionality in the pass file. I cannot share you the valid .pkpass file as it contains ids and keys etc. But can give the pass.json file if some one needs(After removing those keys ofcourse).

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/azhelps/id1040221759?mt=8

Comment: The rendering of the pass, including the font size is controlled by the Wallet app.  Currently, there is no way to adjust the font size manually.  I would suggest you file a feature request with Apple.

Comment: yea, my R&D lead me to believe that also. But then I saw that pass file in the wallet added by the app I gave link to above. Did you check the pass added by that application ? (You would have to change your font size to bold also to know what I am talking about)